# Record every terminal,SSH or console activity on Linux

Tags: python-2.7, keylogger

How do I record every terminal, SSH and console activity in Linux? I would like to do this using Python.

I've tried PyKeylogger but it works only when the user is logged on the gui. It doesn't log terminal and ssh sessions.

PLease help.

Thanks.